# Access a stand alone application from web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, kryo

This may be a stupid question. but i don't have any choice to clarifying it. I have a chat server running in a LAN environment system. And for testing purpose i have deployed my chat client applet into a tomcat server. How to access the server from web page. I have given my local IP address (192.168.0.XXX i know this is very bad). The application is saying access denied. and getting this acception

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 192.168.0.106:54555
```

Comment: Is your tomcat using port 54555?

Comment: Perhaps look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169717/why-does-my-applet-get-a-java-security-accesscontrolexception-access-denied-ja. It looks to be a duplicate.

Comment: no my tomcat port is 8084 and  am  running my server in different system.

Comment: If i run the applet from applet viewer it is connecting to server(CHAT server running on a system). But from web browser it is not.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, then issue may be related to this:
`Applets are specifically prohibited from making network connections from machines other than the host they were downloaded from. The only way around this is by using a digital signature in the applet.`

[Code Signing for Java Applets](http://www.suitable.com/docs/signing.html)

Comment: Is signing is must i have created signing in netbeans IDE(self signing) but it didn't worked for me.