# Applets not opening in Java 1.8 Machine

Tags: java, web-applications, applet, accesscontrolexception

I am using the java applets which will be used as web application . It is working well in java 1.7 PC. Applets could not be viewed in Java 1.8 PC.

I have tried signing the jar with 1.8 Java yet i could not resolve. I am getting below error. Kindly someone help me out

[image: AccessControlException]

Comment: Probably this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169717/why-does-my-applet-get-a-java-security-accesscontrolexception-access-denied-ja

Comment: Just for the record: you understand that applets are "dead technology"; that chrome has abandoned them completely; Java9 will too; and that any investment in this technology will soon render useless?

Comment: 1) Don't post images of exception output, copy the **text** and add it as an [edit] to the question. 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 3) *"I have tried signing the jar with 1.8 Java.."* This reads like you used the tools of a Java 1.8 SDK to 'self-sign' an applet. That won't work anymore. Applets need to be signed with a certificate issued by a trusted CA.